# package.json webpack linting json file with eslint

Tags: json, webpack, eslint

I am trying to lint json files with eslint. Is there a way to do that with esline or is there a plugin I can use for that purpose? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by installing the `eslint-plugin-json` module, then add `'json'` type to the `plugins` section in `.eslintrc`

I can then lint json files like this

```
eslint . --ext .json
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried `eslint-plugin-json`, but it won't auto-fix your json for you, meaning you have to manually fix the lint issues.

So I made [`eslint-plugin-json-format`](https://github.com/Bkucera/eslint-plugin-json-format), which has auto-fixing built-in.

It will also (optionally) sort your package.json for you

```
eslint --ext .json . --fix
```